# Browser history via JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

For many years now, it has been known that a website can use CSS/JS to determine websites that have been visited by a user, e.g.

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Mozilla-to-Fix-8-Year-Old-Browser-History-Leak-Issue-139015.shtml
http://yro.slashdot.org/story/09/07/02/1317205/Your-Browser-History-Is-Showing

There are sites that will use the CSS/JS hack to figure out which websites you have displayed, but I was wondering if anybody knew of a service that will create a URL that I can send to somebody (or put in an invisible iframe) and will then surreptitiously do the browser history hack when the URL is visited and e-mail the results to me?

I know I can set up my own site with BEEF (browser exploitation framework), but I'm lazy.

Thank you.

Frank

Comment: I've heard the phrase "We don't help hackers here" used. I'm also not inclined to help those who describe themselves as lazy.

Comment: Most browsers have fixes in to help prevent this type of attack now. :) http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Comment: The URL of the softpedia contains: "Mozilla to Fix 8 Year Old Browser History Leak Issue". Seems to me it'd be pointless to help you even if I wanted to.

Comment: Hacking can only lead to better security in the future.
If there were no hackers no flaws would be exposed, anybody that didn't want you to know about such flaws would hold you blindfolded and never expose them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason not to help this man.

Here ya go:
http://securityvulns.com/